# Not able to rejoin an XP Pro PC to a windows 2008 Domain Endpoint mapper error

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, domain, rpc

I know many people claim to get this error and that this could be caused by the RPC services or some other registry port limits, however I have spend hours trying to resolve an issue that all started when one computer crashed due to a bad system board. Since we did not have any spare system boards, I resorted to moving the hardrive into another simular computer, same hardware model etc. I then tried to login to this PC and it would only let me login locally. Perthaps this was becuase the network card mac address changed. So here I decided to unjoin the domain and delete this computers name in AD example "computer1" I proceeded to delete in DNS. Next I  to rejoin "computer1" to my same Domain and after about 45 seconds I got the famous endpoint mapper error.

Message states: Computer name changes: the following error has occured: there are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper" Yet I cannot find any specific event logs on either the client PC and or the Domain Controller. I am not able to re-join this computer to my domain with the same computer name "computer1" so this computer remains in a workgroup, yet in active directory the name "computer1" was created again. i find this really strange.

if I try to join the domain with another name like 'computer2' I get the message welcome to my domain, however I get a few clicks latter saying that computer could not be renamed. Yet in active directory in still creates the "computer1" name and not the new name.  Also after rebooting the pc the name computer1 is still present as the local computer name, yet it appears to be joined to the domain as I get the domain dropdown option at login.

Finally I cannot login to "computer1" using any valid domain admin accounts. I get an error: windows cannot contact the Domain Controller, either because......"

I've tried so many things including sysprep the pc, reseting winsock, changing the name while in workgroup first and rebooting first and even then I cannot join the domain, I keep getting the endpoint mapper errors.

What else can be wrong. This hardrive was previously on the domain and working fine. Why won't it let me join it again.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the computer from active directory users and computer and try to rejoin it.if this doesnt work try sysprep
open run and type `%systemroot%\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe` then select enter system out-of-box experience (OOBE)and check generalize.
after rebooting try to rejoin it to your domain.

[check this out for more information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766514%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned that I had already tried sysprep and winsock resets. I re-entered the Ip address, gateway and dns entries each time. This did not work.

Comment: i had this problem but solved with sysprep with checking generalize checkbox,you can try another way,remove the user directory in local machine,and restart pc then try to rejoin it.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely something in network layer

verify that there is not port exhaustion issue

turn off all firewall, antivirus, host intrusion prevention service, etc.

upgrade NIC driver

on client, run portqryUI, select the pre-defined rule set for "domain & trust", select a DC as your target, all major ports should be listed as listening. There are a few non-critical ports can be "not listening".